# Add another service account to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I am running Apache using the service account **httpd**. (Linux box)

I made a user **proj1** and created the virtual directory myproj. I then chowned that directory with:

*chown -R proj1:proj1 myproj*

I login as **proj1** using ftp and can create directories and php code. The problem I can't figure out is how to tell Apache & PHP that it is ok for it to creat/write to the directories of proj1 (E.g mkdir() ).

I would prefer that all directories be created with 755. Is there a way to add **proj1** to be an additional service account to the virtual directory?

P.S. PHP safe mode is off and have root access to this server

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points of mention with regard to you question, so I address them one at a time. First a bit of clarification:

**Apache runs as user httpd**

This means that everything running under apache will be done as the user httpd. 
Specifically, if you run PHP as a module under apache (i.e. mod_php) it will run as httpd.

- If you try to read a file and the user httpd doesn't have access to
  it - you will get a permission denied error.
- If you try to create a
  file, it will be created as the user httpd (and if that user doesn't
  have write permissions, access will be denied).
- You cannot make apache run as multiple users simultaneous (and should have no need to).

**You have a system user: proj1 and you have changed file ownership to this user.**

Since you are logging in as this user via FTP, you will have the permissions of this user - files you upload are owned by 'proj1'. (Presumably - there are other setups possible, but the question seems to suggest this one).

**Your permissions are 755:**

- user: read, write, execute
- group: read, execute
- other: read, execute

You shouldn't need these permissions - 644 should be sufficient - a good setup does not require PHP files to be executable, and removing that permission increases security.

**Now, to your problem:**

You want directories and files created by PHP to be owned by proj1, and for PHP to be able to modify files owned by proj1.

For this to happen PHP must run as proj1. Note - this does not require that Apache runs as proj1. Either:

1. Use FastCGI - Apache's mod_fastcgi with php-fpm

   - Setup a pool specifying the owner as proj1 and the group as proj1.
2. Use Suexec either with mod_php, mod_fastcgi, or mod_fcgi

   - Configure the chosen module (add mod_suexec, FastCgiSuexec, etc as needed). To your VirtualHost, add:

     ```
     SuexecUserGroup proj1 proj1
     ```

Add apache to the proj1 group. Apache will continue to run as httpd - but will be able to read the necessary files since it is part of the group (as long as group as read permissions). PHP will run as proj1 (which should have read, write permissions), thereby resolving your write issues. Also, you can add more virtualhosts later on, each with different permissions by adding more pools to php-fpm or different users with Suexec.

(As a personal preference, I'd favour php-fpm).